# Can you help me understand PHP Classes a little better?

Tags: php, class

I am kind of a slow learner I guess when it comes to coding, I have been learning PHP for a couple of years and I still don't understand Classes so it's time I put some effort in to at least understanding them a little better.

I use functions for everything.  People often make comments to me on here that they can't believe I have a social network site and I don't use classes.

I really do not understand the benefit of them can you explain the benefits besides it supposedly being easiar for multiple people to work on your code?

To me it seems like classes just complicate simple task

Comment: Once you understand classes and their uses, you will understand why they make development so much easier and better structured. Well worth learning.

Comment: Wow .. lots of answers, and every one of them is really long.

Comment: @Christian: Here we are 3 years later and I agree 100% now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply (in fact, extremely simply), classes allow you to organize code in logical units as well as provide containers and templates for user-created objects.

Let's say you have a car... A car can has a capacity and people inside.

```
class Car {
    private $people = array();
    private $capacity;

    function __construct($capacity) { $this->capacity = $capacity; }

    function addPerson($name) {
        if(count($this->people) >= $this->capacity) {
            throw new Exception("Car is already at capacity");
        } else {
            $this->people[] = $name;
        }
    }
    function getPeople() { return $this->people; }
    function getCapacity() { return $this->capacity; }
}
```

Now, we can start using those cars:

```
$aliceCar = new Car(2);
$aliceCar->addPerson("Alice");

$bobCar = new Car(4);
$bobCar->addPerson("Bob");
$bobCar->addPerson("Jake");
```

I now have 2 cars (instances), which holds different data.

```
echo implode(',', $aliceCar->getPeople()); // Alice
echo $aliceCar->getCapacity(); // 2

echo implode(',', $bobCar->getPeople()); // Bob,Jake
echo $bobCar->getCapacity(); // 4
```

I might also want to have a van, which will have an additional property for doors:

```
class Van extends Car {
    private $num_doors;

    function __construct($capacity, $num_doors) {
        parent::__construct($capacity); // Call the parent constructor
        $this->num_doors = $num_doors;
    }

    function getNumDoors() { return $this->num_doors; }
}
```

Now let's use that van:

```
$jakeVan = new Van(7, 5);

// Van is ALSO a Car
$jakeVan->addPerson("Ron"); //Jake is with Bob now, so his son is driving the Van
$jakeVan->addPerson("Valery") //Ron's girlfriend

echo implode(',', $jakeVan->getPeople()); // Ron,Valery
echo $jakeVan->getCapacity(); // 7
echo $jakeVan->getNumDoors(); // 5
```

Now maybe you can see how we could apply those concepts towards the creation of, for example, a `DBTable` and a `User` class.

---

In fact, it's hard to really start explaining why classes simplify one's life without getting into the concepts of Object Oriented Programming (abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism).

I recommend you read the following book. It will help you grasp the core concepts of OOP and help you understand why objects to really make your life easier. Without an understanding of those concepts, it's easy to dismiss classes as just another complication.

## PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice

[PHP 5 Objects, Patterns, and Practice http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BF7MF03NL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804)

Available at [Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804)

Comment: thanks for the example code, its easiar to understand by example.  To me not knowing classes, that seems like so much more code than if you did it with a few functions

Comment: **@jasondavis:** But then how can you have multiple cars with functions? Using arrays and passing the array every single time? And how are you guarantied that you don't have more people than the capacity?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the book.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *huge* topic and even the best answers from the best SOers could only hope to scratch the surface, but I'll give my two cents.

Classes are the foundation of [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).  They are, in a very basic way, object blueprints.  They afford many features to the programmer, including encapsulation and polymorphism.

Encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism are very key aspects of OOP, so I'm going to focus on those for my example.  I'll write a structured (functions only) and then an OOP version of a code snippet and I hope you will understand the benefits.

First, the structured example

```
<?php

function speak( $person )
{
  switch( $person['type'] )
  {
    case 'adult':
      echo "Hello, my name is " . $person['name'];
      break;
    case 'child':
      echo "Goo goo ga ga";
      break;
    default:
      trigger_error( 'Unrecognized person type', E_USER_WARNING );
  }
}

$adult = array(
    'type' => 'adult'
  , 'name' => 'John'
);
$baby = array(
    'type' => 'baby'
  , 'name' => 'Emma'
);

speak( $adult );
speak( $baby );
```

And now, the OOP example

```
abstract class Person
{
  protected $name;

  public function __construct( $name )
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  abstract public function speak();
}

class Adult extends Person
{
  public function speak()
  {
    echo "Hello, my name is " . $this->name;
  }
}

class Baby extends Person
{
  public function speak()
  {
    echo "Goo goo ga ga";
  }
}

$adult = new Adult( 'John' );
$baby  = new Baby( 'Emma' );

$adult->speak();
$baby->speak();
```

Not only should it be evident that just creating new data structures (objects) is easier and more controlled, pay attention to the logic in the speak() function in the first example, to the speak() methods in the 2nd.

Notice how the first one must explicitly check the type of person before it can act?  What happens when you add other action functions, like walk(), sit(), or whatever else you might have for your data?  *Each* of those functions will have to duplicate the "type" check to make sure they execute correctly.  This is the *opposite* of encapsulation.  The data and the functions which use/modify them are not connected in any explicit way.

Whereas with the OOP example, the correct speak() method is invoked based on how the object was created.  This is inheritance/polymorphism in action. And notice how speak() in this example, being a method of the object, is explicitly connected to the data it's acting upon?

You are stepping into a big world, and I wish you luck with your learning.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for the example it's nice seeing it in a way that I understand and a way that I don't, it's like a whole different language

Comment: Finally not a car implements vehicle example! 

Answer (score 2):

In some ways, you are correct. Classes *can* complicate simple tasks, and there certainly is a lot you can accomplish without using them. However, classes also make life a lot easier.

Imagine your life without functions. You would have to use GoTo statements to group together blocks of code. Yuck. Sure, you could accomplish the same things, but you would need to work a lot harder and it would be a lot more difficult for you to share your work with others.

Classes provide a neat way to group together blocks of similar code. Also, they allow you to capture and work with state very easily.

A good definition of a class is a blueprint to create objects.

Comment: Am I right to say that classes just group functions together?

Comment: like I have 5 different date/time functions, they could all be added to 1 date/time class?

Comment: They are meant to group together related data, and the functions that operate on that data.

Comment: You are partially correct, classes group functions (or methods) based on their primary purpose. You may have a static database class with all database related methods residing in it. But you may also have multiple classes with database methods in each one... Have a look at this; http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

Comment: That is one reason to create a class - but certainly not the only one. And yes, five different date/time functions could be added to one date/time class - Most likely as static members.

Comment: Static methods versus ordinary functions make pretty much no difference in PHP, apart for the pseudo-namespace they offer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the single best thing you can do for yourself is to buy/find/borrow a book on Object Oriented Programming.  PHP classes are fundamentally the same as other modern languages (Java, C#, etc.), and once you learn OOP you will understand classes at a level of programming that is completely language-agnostic and can be applied to any OOP project, PHP or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

With classes you can do something like

```
class Stack {
  private $theStack = array();

  // push item onto the stack
  public function push(item) { ... }

  // get the top item from the stack
  public function pop() { ... } 
}
```

This simple example has some benefits.

1. Code outside the class cannot manipulate the array that is used to implement the stack
2. The global namespace is not be polluted with unrelated variables
3. Code that needs to use a stack can simply create an instance of the class (i.e. $myStack = new Stack())

Comment: The best thing bout classes ^^

Comment: thanks for the example, you mention code outside the class cannot manipulate the array, I guess I don't follow because if you are coding then I don't see where anything would manipulate it unless you wanted it too and coded it to do so.  Maybe i'll understand someday

Comment: hes talking about encapsulation.  which basically means data hiding to keep you (the programmer) from accidentally creating overriding $theStack in the global namespace.  

in a world filled with functions and no encapsulation you're forced to have $theStack in the global namespace.  Imagine 6 months later and 600 lines below the initialization of $theStack you create it again forgetting it already exists.  you override its value and your program behaves unexpectedly.  Classes allow modularity and easy maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

A class is like a calculator. You can have ten thousand different calculators that do the same thing, and each of them keep track of their own values and data.

```
$cal1 = new calculator;
$cal2 = new calculator;

$cal1->add(5);
$cal2->add(3);

echo $cal1->show(); // returns 5

echo $cal2->show(); //returns 3
```

Every single calculator can do the same tasks, and run on the same code, but they all contain different values.

If you were not using classes, you would have to individually create each calculator, assign it a variable, and copy and paste for every calculator you wanted to use at once.

```
function add_calc_1();
function add_calc_2();
function add_calc_3();
function subtract_calc_1();
function subtract_calc_2();
function subtract_calc_3();
function multiply_calc_1();
function multiply_calc_2();
function multiply_calc_3();
function divide_calc_1();
function divide_calc_2();
function divide_calc_3();

$total_1;
$total_2;
$total_3;
```

Instead, you can define a single class that is the code for a calculator, and then you can create as many different ones as you want, each with their own counters.

```
class calc
{
   public $total;
   function add();
   function subtract();
   function multiply();
   function divide();
}
$cal1=new calc;
$cal2=new calc;
$cal3=new calc;
```

Comment: I shortened it a little. I took out all the functions 'insides', mainly to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 0):

I use classes for my database tables.

for Example we have

> Id, firstname, lastname

For this i will use a class

```
class user{

    public $Id, $name, $lastname

    public function user($iId){

      Id = $iId;
      firstname = mysql_get('firstname');
      lastname = mysql_get('lastname');
}
```

for performance il use getData_functions to retrieve the data rather than putting them in the constructor. Note the above is just a major idea rather than example of how to structure your classes

But later you can do this for multiple users

```
while(mysql_get('Id')){

    $user = new user('Id');
    $print $user->firstname . " " . $user->lastname;
}
```

they make life easier.

But i will more importantly that making life easier dosent mean its faster.. Because a badly designed class can slow things down.

However for such function that are generic to my global program i dont use classes for them.

Answer (score 0):

As a jokey anecdote, I once described PHP scripting without classes as like soap operas -- flat, and difficult to reuse in real-life situations.  On the other hand, OO-PHP is a bit more like real drama; objects are dynamic, and can be multi-faceted, and while there tends to be variation between their instantiations, they are often based on fundamental dramatic archetypes.

Basically what I'm saying is that it's easier to repurpose and reuse object-oriented code, which makes implementing open-source frameworks and utilities easier.  I find pure scripting in PHP to be extremely difficult to maintain and reuse, and tends to allow for bad security holes that there are a lot of good, preexisting object-oriented utilities for.